# My own post permalinks style in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, url, permalinks

How to make permalinks to posts in hexademical (like site.com/?p=11 to example.com/0x000b)?

Comment: It's for blog about programming =)

Comment: If know some modrewrite, I'm sure you could pull this off by making the post number the digits at the end of the hexadecimal value. It's pretty late here, so I can't think straight and work anything out right now, but if you do some googling about modrewrite, and maybe devise a php function to derive the hex value, I'm sure you'd get something workable. I'll check back tomorrow after I wake up, see if I can't help more than telling you to google, haha sorry.

Comment: I know what I need to use hooks in plugin but at now I can't understand what I neew exactly and how to write a plugin.

Comment: I was tried to understand "Custom permalinks" plugin, but it so difficult for first time :)

Answer (score 0):

I gues you can create a plugin to intercept the request when saving a post and then change the post_name to hex(post->id).

Just hook it the the save_post event. Not sure that is the correct name.

Answer (score 0):

VeroLom, the function you're looking for is [add_rewrite_tag()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_tag) that would let you register a new `%hexcode%` tag that could then be used in your permalinks structure just like `%postname%`. Reference links:

- [Rewrite API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API)
- [WP_Rewrite Class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Rewrite)

Cheers!